# Unit vectors in locally convex spaces

Tags: locally-convex-spaces

Are there unit vectors in locally convex spaces. If yes, how can vectors be normalised in locally convex spaces?

Answer (score 2):

No. A locally convex space only has a topology given by a *family of semi-norms*. There is no canonical way to "normalize" a vector.